# Illegal Argument Exception in Appium framework

Tags: java, selenium, appium, pageobjects

After (foolishly) upgrading Appium Server along with various project libraries, such that I cannot tell which, if any, caused the problem, my previously running Appium framework suddenly started failing upon attempting to locate any elements.

The server starts (either manually via desktop or through the java code) and it launches my emulator (if not already loaded), makes the connection, opens the app (in the case show, simply settings) and fails as soon as it tries to validate that the settings main page is displayed by checking the existence of the "Settings" text:

> Given the settings app is displayed (FAILED)
>   (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement field
>   com.mindtree.pageobjects.SettingsMainPage.header to
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d27c0df4)

The Appium server versions for both desktop and nodeJS is currently 1.7.2 I believe the problem started when I was originally at 1.7.1 or 1.7.2 and it succeeded in doing an auto-update on the desktop version to 1.8.1.

Selenium version is 3.11.0 (tried various flavors from 3.9.0 through 3.13.0)

Appium Java client is 6.0.0-BETA5 (tried 6.0.0-BETA4, 6.0.0, 6.1.0)

Java is 1.8

The JBehave test step that reports the error:

```
@Given("the settings app is displayed")
public void givenTheSettingsAppIsDisplayed() {
    main = new SettingsMainPage(driver);
    if (main.pageLoaded())
        test.logGivenPass("the settings app is displayed");
    else {
        test.logGivenFail("the settings app is displayed");
        fail();
    }
}
```

The corresponding page object snippet:

```
public class SettingsMainPage extends MobilePageObject {

    public SettingsMainPage(AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver) {
        super(driver);
        System.out.println("Settings Main page class has been initialized");
    }

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.TextView[@text='Settings']")
    AndroidElement header;
    @AndroidFindBy(id= "android:id/title")
    List<AndroidElement> titles;
    @AndroidFindBy(id= "android:id/summary")
    List<AndroidElement> summaries;

    public Boolean pageLoaded() {
        return helper.isDisplayed(header);
    }

}
```

Googling this particular error returns a few hits, but no offered solutions.

Any guidance appreciated.

edit: I should add that the failure seems to happen upon initialization of the page object via the page factory, since the text "initialized" is never shown, it fails while trying to initialize all the page elements, specifically the first one, at least according to the error message.

My base page object is below:

```
import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.mindtree.helpers.AppiumUtils;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;

public class MobilePageObject {

    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
    AppiumUtils helper;

    public MobilePageObject(AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver) {

        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(15)), this);
        helper = new AppiumUtils();

    }

}
```

> Edit Update: Downgraded the Appium Server through NodeJS from 1.7.2 to
>   1.7.1.  Result: no change, same error reported.

Comment: I think you should report it at appium java client repo. Did you tried with different JBehave versions also ?

Comment: I did try newer versions of JBehave, but for whatever reason, all other versions other than 4.1 that I tried caused the project to not work at all, to not even process any story files, if I recall correctly.

Comment: I should add that I also tried restoring backups from before this problem happened, at least with the pom.xml file, with no change in running status, which leads me to believe that it is somehow related to either the NodeJS install or the desktop version of Appium.  What I have not tried yet is moving both of those back to 1.7.1, which might be the last version I had that worked, I'm not certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using **Appium server 1.8.1**, **selenium 3.13.0** and **java client 6.1.0**. I use the page object model like following and it works fine.

```
public class SettingsMainPage{

    public SettingsMainPage(AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
        System.out.println("Settings Main page class has been initialized");
    }

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.TextView[@text='Settings']")
    AndroidElement header;
    @AndroidFindBy(id= "android:id/title")
    List<AndroidElement> titles;
    @AndroidFindBy(id= "android:id/summary")
    List<AndroidElement> summaries;

    public boolean pageLoaded() {
       try{

           (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(header));
           return header.isDisplayed();
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           return false;
       }
    }

}
```

And you must define your desiredCapabilities like following:

```
public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> setupDesiredCapabilities(String appPackage, String appActivity,
                                                                       String udid, String platformVersion, boolean noReset) {

        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Android phone");  //any name
        caps.setCapability("udid", udid);   
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", platformVersion);
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", appPackage);
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", appActivity);
        caps.setCapability("noReset", noReset);    //optional


        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(
                    "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            //
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //
        }

        return driver;
    }
```

> Make sure you have define **static AppiumDriver** and use the same
>   driver object to call constructor of each page.

Comment: After further attempts at various versions yesterday (before I saw your posted answer) I was already at your posted version numbers (1.8.1, 3.13.0, and 6.1.0) but now it doesn't even reach the previous step that failed, it fails on a previous step where it's trying to open the connection.`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/json/JsonOutput;` Research points to it being a result of Selenium introducing their own json with 3.12 or so conflicting with another version.

Comment: Also, the time parameter on my page init is supposed to do an implicit wait.  It is optional and I've tried your method of not specifying that parameter before, but it made no difference.  I think the problem is somehow connected to AppiumFieldDecorator, though, because the code never reaches the part to check for the existence (display) of the element, it should have displayed the page obect created message upon instantiation first, and that message never makes it to my output.  It seems to be failing while initializing the elements upon creation of the page object itself.

Comment: I suggest you to use maven/gradle in your project. You problem may be because of jar files. Also you need to define desiredCapabilities properly. I have added how to setup desired capabilities in above answer.

Comment: I've been using maven.  Added additional capabilities settings that you have that I hadn't, no change, still won't run.

Comment: Make sure you have define **static AppiumDriver**  and use the same driver object to call constructor of each page.

Comment: Oddly enough, it was your last comment that finally (seems to have) fixed my problems.  When my regular (not appium) project also suddenly stopped working, I was getting a more-specific nullpointerexception with the driver I discovered that while I was able to avoid using static declarations, apparently with one of the updates (probably Selenium itself) I can no longer do that.  Defining my driver as static fixed my other project, then at least got me further in my Appium project as well, so I'm marking this as the accepted solution, thanks.